# Is there a V4L camera driver for Kinetic?

Tags: ros-kinetic, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I see several usb camera drivers (usb_cam, uvc_camera) that I assume will work w/ a V4L driver, but nothing that supports Kinetic. Am I missing something? Any suggestions (e.g., wipe and install Indigo)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246906/is-there-a-v4l-camera-driver-for-kinetic?/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Am I missing something?

Have you tried building them from sources?

Packages that work on Indigo most likely work in Kinetic as well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2016-11-02**:
Doh! Yes, it compiles and works in Kinetic. Thanks.